# mysql: Select from table1 rows that are missing in table2

Tags: mysql

I've been struggling with this code for a while. I copied it, and altered it from another SO-question, but I cannot get it to work.

I have a table(scores) which holds username, userID and score. and another table called userLocations, which holds userID, city, country, lat and long coordinates.

What I need to do is list every row in scores-table which doesn't have a row in the table userLocation with an identical userID.

```
select scores.userID , case when userLocations.userID is not null then 1 else 0 end as row_exists from scores left outer join (select distinct userID from userLocations) userLocations on scores.userID = userLocations.userID
```

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM scores x LEFT JOIN userlocation y ON y.userid = x.user WHERE y.userid IS NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to get a list of rows in`scores`that don't have matching`userid`in`userLocations`I believe this query should give you that with good performance:

```
select * from scores s
where not exists (
    select 1 from userLocations ul 
    where ul.userID = s.userID
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select scores.userID , case when userLocations.userID is not null then 1 else 0 end as row_exists
from scores left outer join
     (select distinct userID from userLocations) userLocations
     on scores.userID = userLocations.userID;
```

You need a `left join`.  I would also advocate table aliases to make the query easier to write and to read:

```
select s.userID , (case when ul.userID is not null then 1 else 0 end) as row_exists
from scores s left outer join
     (select distinct userID from userLocations) ul
     on s.userID = ul.userID;
```

If you only want rows where `row_exists` is `0`, then add `where ul.userId is NULL` to the query.  Actually, in this case, the best way to write the query is without the subquery:

```
select s.userID , (case when ul.userID is not null then 1 else 0 end) as row_exists
from scores s left outer join
     userLocations ul
     on s.userID = ul.userID
where ul.userId is NULL;
```